# Нейронная сеть, работающая на разнородных данных

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, tensorflow

у меня есть небольшая модель нейронной сети, которую мне предстоит нормально реализовать.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я использовал tensorflow как фреймворк для написания кода и оттуда брал терминологию. Суть в том, что у меня сейчас на вход должно приходить 2 элемента: массив из 8 значений и 4 массива по 104 значения. Я не пойму, как можно такую сеть создавать и обучать. Насколько я читал, можно нейронную сеть тренировать только на тензорных данных определенной размерности. А тут на вход идут 2 тензора. А данные слишком разнородные, чтобы их собирать в 1 тензор. Может мне стоит рассмотреть вообще другой подход или использовать несколько моделей?

Еще второй вопрос, насколько адекватно разделять тензор на части, обрабатывать по отдельности слоями нейронной сети, а потом собирать снова воедино для дальнейшей обработки. Не перепутается ли алгоритм при обратном распространении ошибок? Я использую именно встроенные в тензорфлоу функции.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почитайте про рекуррентные нейронные сети, но вообще не понимаю, почему вы просто не засунете всё это в одну матрицу, а потом не допишете скип пары нейронных слоёв. Просто я тут вижу что-то похожее на RNN, поэтому вы можете организовать что-то подобное и у себя.